# JDBC FOR UPDATE query takes 120Ms+ PER ROW

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, sql-update

I am running the following code to pull records from a database, and then mark the records as being read.

```
public static Future<DBEntry[]> mark(int num) {
    return slaveDriver.submit(new DBSlave() {
        @Override
        public DBEntry[] run(Connection con, DBEntry[] entries) throws SQLException {
            try {
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                String query = "SELECT `email`,`pass`,`status` FROM `" + DB_TABLE + "` WHERE `status`='fresh' AND `script`='test' ORDER BY `" + DB_TABLE +
                               "`.`lastseen` ASC LIMIT ? FOR UPDATE";
                try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {
                    ps.setInt(1, num);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    DBEntry[] entry = valueOf(rs);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        rs.updateString(3, "used");
                        rs.updateRow();
                    }
                    con.commit();
                    return entry;
                }
            } finally {
                con.setAutoCommit(true);
            }
        }
    });
}

protected static Connection getConnection(boolean rbs) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = slavePool.poll();
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + DB_NAME + (rbs ? "?rewriteBatchedStatements=true" : null), DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }
    return conn;
}

public static DBEntry[] valueOf(ResultSet set) throws SQLException {
    int rowcount = 0;
    if (set.last()) {
        rowcount = set.getRow();
        set.beforeFirst();
    }
    DBEntry[] entries = new DBEntry[rowcount];
    for (int i = 0; set.next(); i++) {
        entries[i] = new DBEntry(null, set.getString(1), set.getString(2), "", "", 0, 0, null);
    }
    set.beforeFirst();
    return entries;
}
```

My database:

[image]

The operation is being done remotely. The machines are connected by a 1gbps line, so theoretically I could download all of the records almost instantaneously. However it takes over 120Ms per row and 320 seconds for 2700 rows using the above code. (Less than 0.5Mb for all test rows)

Am I doing something entirely wrong or is this the expected performance?

Also I should note that this needs to be capable of running multiple instances at once without corrupting the records or pulling duplicates, which is the reason for this code:

```
ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
```

As well, the following code seems to speed the process up significantly for all batch queries, which is why it is included:

```
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

I can post a runnable example upon request but I am certain the delays are not caused by any other part of the program as it is blocking in the "mark" method.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably simpler to create a batch of `update` queries rather then trying to modify the `ResultSet`, also, jumping from current cursor position, to the end and back to the start will take time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! I was under the impression that this type of thing was exactly what updateRow() was designed for. I will try writing it where it selects one row at a time, and then updates it in a separate query. Will report back.

Comment: Yeah, you can do, but I'd suspect that you're performing a single operation each time, where as a batch update (or even a single query update) would be quicker generally

Comment: Usage of an updatable result set is generally an anti-pattern, there are usually better alternatives like using a single `update` statement. Your code has more gems, like your hand-rolled connection pool, and the way you iterate at least three times over the result set (first (implicitly) to determine the number of rows, then to fill that `DBEntry[]` and then to mark the rows as read. I hope you realize you could do all that in one go. Populate an `ArrayList` instead so you don't need to get the count, and get the data and mark as used in one go.